# Binomial formula for matrix $(\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{A})^{-1/2}$.

Tags: matrices, binomial-theorem

I am wondering if the following binomial expansion for the matrix is correct:
$$
(\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{A})^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1/2 \\
n
\end{array}\right) \mathbf{A}^n, 
$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is a unit matrix.
If right, is there any existing literature to support the result?

Comment: If $f(A)$ is your series, then for $A$ with small enough eigenvalues, $f(A)$ converges and $f(A)^2=1+A.$ But the series doesn't even converge for all reals ($1\times1$ matrices.) And it is not clear what $B^{1/2}$ means for a matrix $B.$ There are a lot of square roots of the identity matrix, for example.

Comment: But the formal power series $f(x)=\sum \binom{1/2}{n}x^n$ in the ring of formal power series $\mathbb Q[[x]]$ has the property $f(x)^2=1+x,$ so we'd get, in any topological ring $R$ and $r\in R$ such that $f(r)$ converges, that $f(r)^2=1+r.$

Comment: Whoops, wrote those comments for $(1+A)^{1/2},$ but they all apply to $(1+A)^{-1/2},$ too, with obvious adjustments.

Comment: Here we first assume that the series converges.

Comment: The series converges absolutely for $\|A\| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume to be in $\mathbb{C}^N$.) If $A$ is **normal** and the greatest absolute value of the eigenvalues of $A$ is less than $1$, then the identity is true.

The left hand side is defined spectrally. If $A=\sum_l l P_l$ is the spectral decomposition of $A$, where $l$ are its eigenvalues and $P_l$ the orthogonal projectors on the associated eigenspaces,
$$(I+A)^{-1/2}:= \sum_l (1+l)^{-1/2} P_l\:.$$
The proof of the wanted identity is trivial using $A= UDU^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$ (with their multeplicities) on the diagonal and $U$ a suitable unitary matrix (it exists just because $A$ is normal). The series converges absolutely by trivial  use of  the uniform  norm (this norm is the absolute value if the greatest eigenvalue of $A$), but all norms are equivalent in a finite dimensional complex linear space.

(The identity also holds in C* algebras for normal elements and thus also for bounded normal operators in Hilbert spaces, in all cases for $||A||<1$.)